# How to console custom radio value in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created custom radio button.Here is the link [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7od9p95/1/) .
Every thing is working fine except when I try to console the value of radio in angular controller I am getting '(an empty string)'.
This is how I am trying to get radio value.

```
console.log($scope.exist_popup);
```

Comment: I don't see any angular code in the fiddle you provided.

Comment: sorry mate but your Fiddle even doesnt contain Angular library, please fix it

Comment: I have only a button like this : <input type="button" ng-click="getradiovalue()"> Inside getradiovalue function I just console the value of radio but not getting .

Comment: When I switching from "yes" to "No" in radio button. Radio changing the property like ('checked=checked')..